# Keep changes to a variable from an if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I am trying to figure out how to change a variable in an if statement and make it so that the changes stay globally.

User input: !change Hi

```
var A = "Hello"

if (msg.content.includes ('!change')) {
  A = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');
}
msg.send(A); //the change won't stick outside the if statement
```

Output: Hello

I did some reading and also tried using a function but I couldn't get that to work either.

```
var A = "Hello"

if (msg.content.includes ('!change')) {
  B = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');

  changetext(B)
}


function changetext(altText){
A=altText
}

msg.send(A); //the change won't stick here either
```

Sorry if I am not being overly clear, I am trying my best lol. My goal is to have it so a user can input "!change Hi" and then the change will stay outside the if statement and A="Hi". Hopefully that makes sense. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run this solution, I think it does what you need already, If not, please specify what's wrong with the output in the comments

```js
var A = "Hello";
var msg = {
content:'!cahnge Hello'
}

if (msg.content.includes ('!change')) {
  A = msg.content.replace('!change ', '');
}
console.log(A);
```